# Django exception process in production mode

Tags: python, django

I built a inventory management system using Django. When I sale some products, I need to check whether there are enough products in system. I rewrite save function in models.py and raise an exception when quantity is less than 0. I want to get the exception and show it in views.py. However, no details are showed on web when raising an exception. How  should I do, or whether there is other method to solve my need?

Here is code:

```py
# views.py
def custom_exception_handler(request, exception):
    if isinstance(exception, ValueError):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        error_message = str(exception)
        return render(request, '500.html', context={'error_message': error_message}, status=500)
```

```py
# models.py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = Stock.objects.get(id=self.stock_id.id)   
        left_quantity = obj.quantity - self.quantity
        if left_quantity < 0:
            raise ValueError('No enough inventory')
        defaults = {'quantity': left_quantity, 'update_time': self.consume_time}
        for key, value in defaults.items():
            setattr(obj, key, value)
        obj.save()
        super(RepairOutStock, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```py
# settings.py
handler500 = 'spare_parts.views.custom_error_view'  # 500 error
```

```html
# templates/500.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<h2>{{ error_message }}</h2>
</html>
```

Comment: Check if `Debug` is `True`. You might have missed that.

Comment: Debug is False. I want to show details in production mode.

Comment: You specified your handler in your settings.py file. Move it to your root URLconf file. Specifying it anywhere else will not work. [See Customizing error views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move this code from your settings file to your Root URLconf file.

```py
# settings.py
handler500 = 'spare_parts.views.custom_error_view'  # 500 error
```

> Specify the handlers as seen below in your URLconf (setting them anywhere  else will have no effect). 
> [Django docs -customizing error
> views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views)

Mind you, each view you specify as a handler is expected to [behave in a certain way.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/urls/#handler500)

Comment: After I move handler500 to Root URLconf file. I got an exception about the parameter in custom_exception_handler function.

`Exception in thread django-main-thread:

ERRORS:
?: (urls.E007) The custom handler500 view 'spare_parts.views.custom_error_view' does not take the correct number of arguments (request).`

Comment: Change the function signature to `def custom_exception_handler(request, exception = None)` as shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views). Also return [`HttpResponseServerError`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseServerError) as mentioned [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/urls/#handler500)

Comment: Thanks for your repley. I am just wondering whether I can get the exception message "No enough inventory". When I set exception=None and repeat again, the exception is None instead of "No enough inventory". Is there any method to get the exception message?

Comment: `error_message = str(exception)` works doesn’t it? If `isinstance(exception, ValueError)` returns true then the rest of the code should work.

Comment: I use breakpoint to test and print the exception. The exception still None instead of "No enough inventory". `def custom_error_view(request, exception=None):
    print(exception)`

Comment: @David the 500 error handler does not get the exception as an argument. Given a 500 error usually means something that the server hasn't handled that makes sense to me. Why are you trying to handle that separately anyway? Can you not catch the error in the view responsible for calling `save`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am new to django. At the beginning, I raised value error when the quantity was less than 0 in save function of models.py. This worked in DEBUG=True. But when I wanted to set DEBUG=False, I found I only got the server 500 error. I wanted show more information for user such as "No enough inventory". It may be not the ideal design. If you have any suggestion, I would really appreciated for it.

Comment: Check first if [ValueError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) is good here. If it is, then it’s not bad design. I don’t think it is good here though but that is debatable.

Comment: @David It's not ideal design because you are not handling that exception at all, that situation can be said to be exceptional for the `save` function but for the particular view in question you seem to be expecting for that to happen. Which means you should have a`try` block to catch that exception and handle it with an appropriate response for the user.